# How to read ADF output log in Log analytics-Count of Read rows ,count of written rows and processing time

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am trying read ADF output log using Log analytics. To get this I am trying to read Output column of ADFActivityRun table of log analytics.
I want to get Read and written count of adf pipeline but which is exist at multiple place bit different node name in json.below is the just example of json.
how to get using Read and written count from a json which is at multiple places and unstructured
"Met":{ "updatedRec":{ "rowsWritten":"458" "RowsRead":"123" "time" :"256" } "InsertRecord":{ "Dest":{ "idletime":"546" "RowsRead":"123" "rowsWritten":"458" } } }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK8rQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

> how to get using Read and written count from a json which is at multiple places and unstructured.

As you are getting **unstructured Json in ADFActivityRun output column** the only way is to split that with the `"` and it will create an array of the elements then with the proper index number access the element which you want.

For below unstructured Json it will split like `[Met,:{,updatedRec,:{ ,rowsWritten,:,458,.............]`

```sql
ADFActivityRun 
| extend parsedJson = split('"Met":{ "updatedRec":{ "rowsWritten":"458" "RowsRead":"123" "time" :"256" } "InsertRecord":{ "Dest":{ "idletime":"546" "RowsRead":"123" "rowsWritten":"458" } } }','"') 
| project rowsWritten = tostring(parsedJson[7]),RowsRead = tostring(parsedJson[11]),Processingime = tostring(parsedJson[15])
| distinct Processingime, RowsRead, rowsWritten
```

[image]

For structured Json you can use parse Json function and access the properties with `.` parameter

```sql
ADFActivityRun 
| extend parsedJson = parse_json(Output)
| project rowsWritten = tostring(parsedJson.dataWritten),RowsRead = tostring(parsedJson.dataRead),Processingime = tostring(parsedJson.copyDuration)
| distinct Processingime, RowsRead, rowsWritten
```

[image]